# Algorithm to find most efficient way to send data parallely

Tags: c++, algorithm

There are 2 computers A and B. Computer A can send data at x MB/s and computer B at y MB/s. 
**Example** - If x = 20, y = 10 and Z = 100 then minimum time would be 4 sec because computer A can send 80 MB data in 4 seconds and B can send 20 MB in 2 sec parallely.
The algorithm given below has a time complexity of O(n^2). How can we solve it in a more efficient way?

**EDIT** - How can it be done for n computers and find the data being sent from each computer? 
**My Solution** -

```
int main()
{
    int x = 50;
    int y = 10;
    int Z = 200;

    vector<int> xvec, yvec;
    for(int i = x;i <= Z; i+= x)
    {
        xvec.push_back(i);
    }

    for(int i = y;i <= Z; i+= y)
    {
        yvec.push_back(i);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < xvec.size(); i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < yvec.size(); j++)
        {
            if(xvec[i] + yvec[i] >= Z)
            {
                cout << "min time : " << i+1;
                exit(0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You defined `x` and `y`, but what is `Z`?

Comment: O(1) by `time = (Z + (x + y) - 1) / (x + y)`?

Comment: I guess the integer constraint makes it difficult. Without integer constraint the solution is 3.33 seconds. We can not simply round 3.33 up to 4 and assume a solution exists. E.g [x, y, z]=[2, 3, 4] case, Optima is 0.8, but rounding it up to 1 is not correct, for the best feasible solution is (x*2 + y*0).

Comment: But how can I find the data which is being sent in min time from all computers ?

Comment: Never under-estimate the bandwidth of a lorry filled with LTO tapes :-)

Comment: @Downvoter Can you please specify the reason for downvote ?

Answer (score 0):

If the question is realy to calculate it for those two nodes, then the comments to your question are fine. If the question was to calculate for an arbitrary number of nodes, then your problem is an instance of the flow problem in graphs. So, encode your problem in a graph and use a known standard algorithm for it, e.g., Ford-Fulkerson O(|V|*|E|*u_{max}), Edmund Karp O(|V|*|E|^2), or Dinic O(|V|^2*|E|).
After you found your maximum flow, you can divide amountof data by your max. flow.

Answer (score 0):

> How can it be done for n computers ?

The logic `z/(x1+x2+...+xn)` is the most efficient and easy way to understand the logic.

Using the function `ceil` will provide that you have the surplus part for many calculations, for example 50 MBs and 3 computers with speeds 5 MB, 4 MB and 2 MB per second. After the calculation, your possible min time is `50/(5+4+2)=4.54` and system will wait for one more second after 4 seconds to handle `0.54 s` part (will decide which computer to execute-probably the fastest one).

Comment: This algorithm won't specify the data being sent from individual computers.